# How do I correct my htaccess for proxying search engine crawl requests?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, reactjs

I have built a website with React at the front end and WordPress as the backend. For search engine crawlers to see my site, I have set up prerendering at the server side, and am trying to set up htaccess to proxy requests coming from search engines so that they are served pre-rendered pages.

For testing, I am using the "Fetch as Google" tool in Google Webmasters.

Here is my attempt:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Proxy the request ... works for inner pages only
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?)$ http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My problem is that this directive doesn't work for my home page, and works only for inner pages (http://example.com/inner-page/):

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?)$ http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

When I change this line to the following line, the home page request is indeed proxied correctly, but the inner pages stop working.

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?(.*) http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Could you help me fix the rewrite rule so that my home page is also proxied correctly for the googlebot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I tried this, and used the Fetch as Google tool to test. Only the inner pages are getting crawled. The home page still shows a "Not found" error in my Google webmasters tool.

Comment: Could it be because of the trailing slash that is always used by the Fetch as Google tool?

Comment: I change my rule with optional trailing slash. You can try

Comment: I used your updated new rule. I still get a "Not Found" error in my Fetch as Google tool. What do you think could be the issue?

Comment: If you try without all `RewriteCond` (or test condition) do you see the page ?

Comment: I tried removing all RewriteCond lines except the one with %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} under this block <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>   Still, I get Not Found for the Home page and fetch works correctly for inner pages.

Comment: It seems to me that with what you indicate in your question It should never work with proxy. Are sure to display the correct prerendering version during your tests ?

Comment: If you visit this link http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/ with or without the trailing slash, you will be able to see the pre-rendered page in the browser. I am trying to show Googlebot this page, instead of example.com. Example.com is loaded through React and Googlebot sees nothing there.

Comment: I understand your problem. I just wondered if you could see the online version thinking to see the pre-rendered version. For the rest, I have no other idea ... sorry

Comment: It seems to me that we see the same version with the two links.

Comment: They are nearly the same version, but different. Difference is that the pre-rendered version has no JavaScript. The live version is rendered through JavaScript. I want Google to see pre-rendered.

Comment: I have no other idea ... sorry

Answer (score 1):

First avoid the repetetions

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Proxy the request ... works for inner pages only
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?)$ http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Then change `^(?!.*?)$` to `^.*$` or with a good pattern like `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*`. Don't forget to use 0 or more flag (`*`) there.

The correct code will be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Proxy the request ... works for inner pages only
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:3000/https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```